# Trigger to Insert Child Object Records

Tags: apex, trigger, error

On update of a Parent Object (Recipe Sheet) to be set to "Add to Inventory" I need to add Child Records (Recipe Sheet Items) based on another table in Salesforce tied to the Product table (Product Items), then I need to update the "Add to Inventory" field to False.

I am currently receiving this error: "There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was

> Apex trigger CreateRecipeItems2 caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: CreateRecipeItems2: execution of
>   AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   de-reference a null object: Trigger.CreateRecipeItems2: line 46,
>   column 1.

Referring to this row:

```
ritem2.Quantity__c = pilist2.External_Wall_Mount_Vaulted_Ceiling__c*RQuantity;
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
trigger CreateRecipeItems2 on Recipe_Sheet__c (after Update) {
    List<Id> recShts = new List<Id>();
    List<Id> recPrds = new List<Id>();

    List<Recipe_Sheet__c> RecipeList = new List<Recipe_Sheet__c>();
    List<Product_Item__c> ProductItemlist = new List<Product_Item__c>();
    List<Product2> ProductList = new List<Product2>();
    List<Recipe_Sheet_Item__c> RecipeItemList = new List<Recipe_Sheet_Item__c>();

    for(Recipe_Sheet__c rec : trigger.new){
        if(rec.Add_To_Inventory__c == true){
            recShts.add(rec.Id); //Stores the Id of the Recipe_Sheet__c in the list
            recPrds.add(rec.Product__c); //Stores the Id of the Product on the Recipe_Sheet__c in the list
        }
    }


    ProductList = [select Id,Name,Do_Not_Discount__c,Record_Type_Id__c 
        from Product2 where Id IN: recPrds];
    ProductItemList = [select Id,Product__c,Quantity__c,Item__c,Length_in_inches__c,
        External_Wall_Mount_Vaulted_Ceiling__c,Standard_Item__c 
        from Product_Item__c where Product__c IN: recPrds ];
    Recipelist  = [Select Id,Opportunity__c,Product__c,Quantity__c,Add_To_Inventory__c,
        For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c,Wall_Mount_Stem__c 
        from Recipe_Sheet__c where Id IN: recShts];        

    for(Recipe_Sheet__c rs : Recipelist ){

    Double RQuantity = rs.Quantity__c;

    if (rQuantity == null)
        rQuantity = 0;   

    for(Product_Item__c pilist :ProductItemlist ){
        if(rs.For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c == 'No'&& rs.Wall_Mount_Stem__c == 'No'){
            Recipe_Sheet_Item__c ritem = new Recipe_Sheet_Item__c();
            ritem.Recipe_Sheet__c = Recipelist[0].Id;
            ritem.Item__c = pilist.Item__c;
            ritem.Quantity__c = pilist.Quantity__c*RQuantity ;
            RecipeItemList.add(ritem);
        }
    }

    for(Product_Item__c pilist2 :ProductItemlist ){
        if(rs.For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c == 'Yes'|| rs.Wall_Mount_Stem__c == 'Yes'){
            Recipe_Sheet_Item__c ritem2 = new Recipe_Sheet_Item__c();
            ritem2.Recipe_Sheet__c = Recipelist[0].Id;
            ritem2.Item__c = pilist2.Item__c;
            ritem2.Quantity__c = pilist2.External_Wall_Mount_Vaulted_Ceiling__c*RQuantity;
            RecipeItemList.add(ritem2);
        }
    }

    if (!RecipeItemList.isEmpty()){
        insert RecipeItemList ;
    }

    for(Recipe_Sheet__c RS1 :Recipelist ){
        RS1.Add_To_Inventory__c=False;
    }

    update Recipelist;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to multiple a null value by something:

```
ritem2.Quantity__c = pilist2.External_Wall_Mount_Vaulted_Ceiling__c*RQuantity;
```

Either **pilist2.External_Wall_Mount_Vaulted_Ceiling__c** or **RQuantity** is null.  Make sure they have a value before multiplying.

You said **RQuantity** is null.  Add in a check:

```
if (rQuantity == null)
  rQuantity = 0;
```

EDIT:  Also the following(this doesn't really hurt anything besides adding unnecessary lines):

```
Double Rquantity;
RQuantity = rec.quantity__c;
```

Can be changed to:

```
DoubRQuantity = rec.Quantity__c;
```

There is no reason to use 2 lines for it.

Comment: For some reason it thinks RQuantity does not have a value because if I remove that piece I do not get this error. Am I not passing the value into this variable correctly? As the Recipe Sheet Quantity is populated on my record.

Comment: rec.quantity__c probably doesn't have a value.  Use a debug here to confirm.  If it doesn't have a value, assign it to 0.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: How do I assign it to 0?

Comment: I show how in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to add that piece but now I get this error: "Error:Apex trigger CreateRecipeItems2 caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CreateRecipeItems2: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a07Z000000HnzecIAB; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]: Trigger.CreateRecipeItems2: line 47, column 1"

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not completely sure.  What line is that?  Did you remove any of those commented insert lines because that could cause the error.  Btw, it's probably better to be doing this in a **before insert** trigger so that you can remove **update Recipelist;**

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if both fields used in the assignment have a value.

Comment: I must not be assigning the Recipe_Sheet__c.Quantity__c correctly because if I remove Rquantity I do not get an error. Any thoughts here?

Comment: You could set a default value of 0 on that field or mark is as required or check if it has a value before performing the calculation.

Comment: How do I seet the default value? Also the record I am testing with absolutely has a value in the quantity field as it set to required so I am not sure why it wouldn't be pulling it through.

Comment: Could be the other field, have you done a system.Debug on both fields to the right of the assignment?

Comment: I am fairly new at apex. What is the best way to run a system.Debug?

Comment: Found a post that explains it: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008wiLIAQ